# how to use libjsonrpc-cpp's precompiled dependencies for Windows? #include header files gives errors

Tags: c++

I tried to use libjsonrpc cpp in Windows with precompiled dependencies available in https://spiessknafl.at/libjson-rpc-cpp/libjson-rpc-cpp_win32-deps.zip. (Extracted zip and place win32-deps under root directory) I tried to follow the example in https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp. I created class file MyStubServer. include header files gives ( #include "abstractstubserver.h" and #include ) error "unresolved inclusion". How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **step 2**, you need to generate the `"abstractstubserver"` class, which should create the required header file, so you can include it.